# Assertion failed: (fixture->m_body == this)

Tags: iphone, c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

We have two vectors of fixtures (all of one body)

```
//Create and add fixtures to vector1 and vector2
b2PolygonShape shape1;
shape1.SetAsEdge(from1,to1);
vector1.push_back( body1->CreateFixture(&shape1,0) );

b2PolygonShape shape2;
shape2.SetAsEdge(from2,to2);
vector2.push_back( body2->CreateFixture(&shape2,0) );
```

When case event1, we destroy first fixture in vector1.

```
body1->DestroyFixture( vector1[0] ); //destroy first fixture1
vector1.erase( vector1.begin() ); //remove from vector1
```

When case event2, we destroy first fixture in vector2.

```
body2->DestroyFixture( vector2[0] ); //destroy first fixture2
vector2.erase( vector2.begin() ); //remove from vector2
```

**Problem:**
Sometimes, when we DestroyFixture(...), we get "**Assertion failed: (fixture->m_body == this)**"

I checked, and I know that vector1 can have some fixture2, or vector2 have fixture1. Why it can be? 
I add fixture1 only to vector1, and fixture2 only to vector2.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in the collision callback functions, don't. Box2D prohibits removing bodies/fixtures during collision events. Instead, flag the body for post-collision processing later, for example in the next update method call.